# OCaml How to use a set?

Tags: set, ocaml

I'm looking forward to use a set.
I need keep pairs of integer and I need to find pair in set in fast time.
How to I may use a Set ?
Some example?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small example.

```
# module IPSet = Set.Make(struct type t = int * int let compare = compare end);;
module IPSet : sig ... end
# let myset = IPSet.singleton (3, 8);;
val myset : IPSet.t = <abstr>
# IPSet.mem (3,8) myset;;
- : bool = true
# IPSet.mem (8,3) myset;;
- : bool = false
```